# Create function to flip text position

Tags: jquery

need to create a function when the container calls the number "1, 2, 3, 4" flip the position of the text. If the text is on the left goes right, if you are on the right goes left.

```
<div class="container container1">
    <p>box1</p>
</div>
<div class="container container2">
    <p>box2</p>
</div>
<div class="container container3">
    <p>box3</p>
</div>
<div class="container container4">
    <p>box4</p>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
function invert(container){
    var container = $('.container');   
    $('container').css('text-align','right');
}

invert(2); //2 is the corresponding number of the section to flip the text ".container 2"
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/17byruh1/)

Comment: Why are you overwriting the `container` variable instead of using it?

Comment: I never did a function with parameter, I need to change the parameter by position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `container` parameter to select the desired element

```
function invert(container) {
    var element = $('.container').eq(container-1); // Subtract 1 because `.eq()` is zero-based
    if (element.css('text-align') == 'right') {
        element.css('text-align', 'left');
    } else {
        element.css('text-align', 'right');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion in you code, you try to apply the CSS change to a string called container.

Can you check that and see if it's what you want :

http://jsfiddle.net/17byruh1/1/

```
function invert(container){
    var dom = $('.container'+container);   
    $(dom).css('text-align','left');
}

invert(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the css property of alignment. Here a link

```
function invert(container) {
     var dom  = $('.container'+container);
     if (dom.css('text-align') == 'right') {
         dom.css('text-align', 'left');
     } else {
         dom.css('text-align', 'right');
     }
}
invert(4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17byruh1/3/